# Clean up (re-allotted question)

Tags: discussion, cleanup

I have been given (re-allotted) questions that I have previously commented on. Trying to prod the OP to respond. (not flagged)

While waiting these questions are making a second or third round. I also note that I have received questions previously allotted to others with similar properties in comments that are from just 3 days ago.

1) Can the clean-up script determine activity, or lack of, on a question before reissuing? 
2) Do you want these questions that make round two handled differently or just ignore them and move on?

Comment: I've had this problem too. I think it'd be nice for the question for a button to say "ok multiple people have tried this question and it's abandoned, too localize" button.

Comment: Very Good idea @Oli